# How to add native library dependencies to sbt project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to add a Java library (e.g. [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)) to an `sbt` project.

This is the Ivy dependency:

```
dependency org="org.apache.pdfbox" name="pdfbox" rev="1.8.2"
```

I first tried to do the following:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.pdfbox" %% "pdfbox" % "1.8.2"
```

But it gives me errors of the type

```
[warn] ==== public: tried [warn]  
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox_2.10/1.8.2/pdfbox_2.10-1.8.2.pom
```

So I understand that with this syntax I can just manage Scala dependencies. I am sure that there is a way to manage Java dependencies, but how?

I tried to search in Google for "sbt add java dependencies" but did not find (recognize) a relevant result.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should replace the `%%` (double percent) with single one.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.pdfbox" % "pdfbox" % "1.8.2"
```

The double-percent is a convenience operator, and causes adding the `_`+`scalaVersion` postfix inside the path, which is `_2.10` in your case. Single percent should fix the problem.

Comment: TL;DR on a 4 line answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.pdfbox" % "pdfbox" % "1.8.2"
```

For java libraries, and

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.8"
```

For Scala libraries, where the difference is the double % for the scala library.

**Long answer:**

Scala is not backward compatible across major version, so a library compiled for scala 2.12.x cannot be used by a project written in scala 2.13.x.

So when writing a scala library, you will need to compile and publish it one time per scala major version you would like to support. When using a library in a project, you would then have to pick the version compiled for the same Scala major version as your are using. Doing this manually would be cumbersome, so SBT has built in support for it.

When publishing a library, you can add the crossScalaVersions key to SBT like

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq( "2.10.6", "2.11.11", "2.12.3" )
```

And then publish with `sbt +publish`.  This will make SBT build and publish a version of the library for both scala 2.10.6, 2.11.11 and 2.12.3. Note that the minor number is in-relevant, when it comes to compatibility for libraries. The published libraries, will have the name suffixed with `_2.10`, `_2.11` and `_2.12` to show what scala version it is for.  An alternative to using the SBT build in support for this, is to use the experimental plugin [sbt-projectmatrix](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-projectmatrix) as this gives a lot more options, and often faster builds.

When using a library sbt can also help your use the one compiled for the correct scala version, and thats where %% comes into play. When specifying a library without the _ suffix in the name, but instead use %%, then sbt will fill in suffix matching the Scala major version your use, and thereby fetch the correct version of the library.